# Select Table Result in Blue Prism

Tags: automation, robotics, blueprism

I need to select multiple rows of a table using Blue Prism. The options will never vary and I know what I need to select. A human would do this by selecting Option 1, then pressing and holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> whilst selecting Option 2 and Option 3.

How can I do this within Blue Prism? I know I need to use `Send Keys` but what is the structure I would use? The values for each of the options will be contained with `Data Items`.

Answer (score 0):

To press and hold keyboard button using sendkeys, you need to use this syntax:

```
"<{CTRL}>"
```

After you click all the necessary actions, then you can reset the control button using this syntax

```
"{CTRL}"
```

Comment: Thank you. And how would I go about clicking on lines with the input being a data item? Do I need to do it as different navigate actions? So action 1 is "<{CTRL}>", next is click Data Item 1, next is click Data item 2 etc?

Comment: Yes, that's how I'd do that. 1. Press and hold CTLR button 2. Click Data_A 3. Click Data_B 4.Press CTRL again to release it

Comment: Does this work on Send Keys or does this only work on Send Key Events? I thought this only worked with Send Key Events personally but could be wrong.edit: https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-7-0/en-us/Guides/global-send-keys/global-send-keys.htm here the docs don't mention it explicitly but they show key pressing happening in events not in normal send keys.